# Netmiko - Read Timeout error for arista eos device -netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout: - Python scripting

Tags: python, netmiko

We are trying to ssh into arista eos device using python netmiko module. We are getting read timeout error when we execute the script . We checked telnet to ip with port 22 . we are able to connect using telnet . Please find the below code

```
    from netmiko import ConnectHandler

arista_vEOS  = {
        'device_type': 'arista_eos',
        'ip': '192.168.12.12',
        'username': 'asasasa',
        'password': 'ddasasas'
    }

print('Insert the IP of the Arista vEOS device:')
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**arista_vEOS)
print('----- Trying to establish a SSH connection with ' + arista_vEOS['ip'] + '... -----')
print('SSH connection successfully created!')
output = net_connect.send_command('show log 10')
print('Show IP Interfaces:')
print(output)
```

Error which we are getting :

```
Insert the IP of the Arista vEOS device:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arultest.py", line 11, in <module>
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**arista_vEOS)
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 344, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 434, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 440, in _open
    self._try_session_preparation()
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 879, in _try_session_preparation
    self.session_preparation()
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/arista/arista.py", line 16, in session_preparation
    self.set_terminal_width(command=cmd, pattern=r"Width set to")
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1235, in set_terminal_width
    output = self.read_until_pattern(pattern=pattern)
  File "/appl/pyenv_3.8/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 651, in read_until_pattern
    raise ReadTimeout(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout:

Pattern not detected: 'Width set to' in output.

Things you might try to fix this:
1. Adjust the regex pattern to better identify the terminating string. Note, in
many situations the pattern is automatically based on the network device's prompt.
2. Increase the read_timeout to a larger value.

You can also look at the Netmiko session_log or debug log for more information.
```

Could you please assist .

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the sample code that provides the netmiko connection to the device with the prompt feature as follows. It will be enough to open a notepad that creates a user&pass and ip list.

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from netmiko import Netmiko

with open("ip_list.txt","r") as f: # you should open ip lists
olt_list_huawei = f.readlines()

with open("user_pass.txt", "r") as f5:
    user_pass = f5.readlines() # you should create user&password list

def _ssh_(nodeip):
    try:
        arista_vEOS = {
            'device_type': 'arista_eos', 'ip': nodeip, 'username':
            username, 'password': password, }
        net_connect = Netmiko(**arista_vEOS)
        print(nodeip.strip() + "  " + "success entered")
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return

    prompt_arista_fnk = net_connect.find_prompt()
    hostname_fnk = prompt_arista_fnk.strip("<" + ">")
    print(hostname_fnk)
    net_connect.send_command_timing("enable")  
    output = net_connect.send_command_timing("config")
    print("config mode entered")

f_2 = open("ip_list.txt","r")
ip_list = f_2.readlines()
f_2.close()

myPool = ThreadPool(100)
result = myPool.map(_ssh_,ip_list)
```